# How to display javascript ad unit inside an article by using insertAdjacentHTML method

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call a google ad sense code inside an article, But i don't want to past ad sense code in middle of an article. For that i am trying some thing like bellow, but it is not working as i expected because of java script issues.

```js
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myArticle").querySelectorAll("p");
x[1].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', '<script>document.write(2+1)</script>' );
</script>
```

```html
<div id="myArticle">
  <p>A heading with class="example" in div</p>
  <p>A paragraph with class="example" in div.</p> 
  <p>A paragraph with class="example" in div.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `</script>` inside your string terminates the script.

You can use something like `"</sc" + "ript>"` or `"<\/script>"` to prevent this.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myArticle").querySelectorAll("p");
x[1].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', '<script>document.write(2+1)<\/script>' );
```

```html
<div id="myArticle">
  <p>A heading with class="example" in div</p>
  <p>A paragraph with class="example" in div.</p> 
  <p>A paragraph with class="example" in div.</p>
</div>
```

Note that the script in `script` elements inserted like this won't run automatically. If you want to run some string, you can use `eval`. Use it carefully.

```js
eval('document.write(2+1)');
```

```html
<div id="myArticle">
  <p>A heading with class="example" in div</p>
  <p>A paragraph with class="example" in div.</p> 
  <p>A paragraph with class="example" in div.</p>
</div>
```

You shouldn't use `document.write`, though. See the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29).

Comment: Dear Oriol, Thanks for your answer, But it is not working.  Can you please test it once again.

Comment: @venkataramana Define 'working'. In fact I don't understand what your goal is.